# Increasingly Opaque area over ios7 native select Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios7

If you have a "select" element in a web app written with Jquery Mobile (v1.4), when running in iOS7 with data-native-menu="true" (Default) you get the iOS7 Spinner picker.  That is fine, but as the "select" gets further down the page (ie There is other content before the select) the picker window gets increasingly opaque to the point where it is unusable.

I think this may be because the spinner is "transparent" and is expecting a white background beneath it, but how would you make that happen?

Example (please run on iPhone with iOS7):

http://eventingedge.com/mobile/demos/picker

Comment: More info: It is that the picker is "transparent". If I add a white div of 400px in height after the 2nd "Select" then the picker has a white(ish) background. But the page is artificially longer than it needs to be. You can then scroll the page with your finger with the picker open and as you approach the new end of page, it will get darker again. So the picker is overlaying the dark grey "background" that is behind the page (which you normally see if you try to scroll too far). I don't know how to influence this "ultimate background" - it is not the background on the body (I tried that!).

Comment: it's the browsers background not the page, test this one your iPhone, open either select at the bottom and while spinner is open, drag page up and down http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/t8TJT/show tested on iphone ios7.

Answer (score 0):

@Omar - yes it is the browser background. Your fiddle has text after the last select - which reduces (but doesn't eliminate) the problem. This is basically the same as my idea of a 400px height white div and this seems like a viable workaround for a web app.

However, my ultimate target is PhoneGap/Cordova which sets the webView background to black - potentially making the situation even worse!  However, it also allows the problem to be eliminated (in the PhoneGap/Cordova (3.3.0) environment)  by editing MainViewController.m:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    //theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //iOS7 changed to white so pickers at end of page have base white  colour
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

This changes the base webview color to white and therefore gives a white background for the end of page pickers.

Comment: I've added text on purpose to show you that it's a browser's background issue, but not to eliminate the problem.